# Installing tweepy for tweeter 2qgis?

Tags: qgis

I installed the plugin "tweeter 2qgis", I need the Python library "tweepy".

Downloading the plugin, a dialog window appeared, saying "we will download tweepy to your temp folder, but you must install it by yourself!".

Ok, before several minutes I've finally found this folder, but the extention's file is **.py** and I can't open anything. I have Windows, maybe is because of this?

Answer (score 2):

[Tweepy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy) is a python module, like any other module you must install it to the Python instance you wish to use. To use it within the plugin you must install it to your Qgis Python instance (located in your OSGeo4W folder on windows).

For instructions on installing into Qgis's python you can see this [guide](http://quantumofgis.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/qgis-standalone-and-python-modules.html).